# How to display SVG from code in LWC salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am calling the API (GET API).

https://upiqr.in/api/qr?name=SantanuSinha&vpa=9096213138@ybl&amount=100
I am calling the API from the LWC

I get the response in the SVG format.

How can I display the SVG that I get in the response on LWC

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the full svg as text? like `<svg>content</svg>`, then simply use query selector on a desired div and put innerHtml = response.

Comment: or you can use an iframe to display it